# Error running npm install: No compatible version found: async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, npm

I have caolan/async added in my package.json as

```
"async": "~0.9.0",
```

npmjs page of async has "0.9.0 published 7 months ago by caolan" written on their website. When I install using npm install it gives me error

```
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: async@'>=0.9.2-0 <0.10.0-0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4","0.1.5","0.1.6","0.1.7","0.1.8","0.1.9","0.1.10","0.1.11","0.1.12","0.1.13","0.1.14","0.1.15","0.1.16","0.1.17","0.1.18","0.1.19","0.1.20","0.1.21","0.1.22","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5","0.2.6","0.2.7","0.2.8","0.2.9","0.2.10","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.4.1","0.5.0","0.6.0","0.6.1","0.6.2","0.7.0","0.8.0","0.9.0"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-36-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/pickingo/pickingo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/pickingo/pickingo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: Do you receive the same error if you remove the `~`?

Comment: `npm install async@latest --save`

Answer (score 11):

To fix the error, you should update your version of `npm`.  `npm`@1.4.28 did not understand the `~` operator in versions.

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

After that, you should have npm 2.1.16 (or newer) and your `npm install` should succeed.